# Why is my custom getView Not called?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I am not familiar with making custom adapters, however I have seen and followed many examples I've seen online. I do not know why my getView is not getting called.

Here is the code:

```
private String[] numbers = new String[] {

"42", "0", "0", "39", "32", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "45", "0", "51",
        "36", "35", "20", "0", "22", "0", "53", "0", "1", "2", "0", "16",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "5",
        "6", "0", "0", "0", "57", "0", "0", "64", "7", "0", "0", "0" };



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//other code
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridViewGame);
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.item_layout, R.id.editTextGridItem, numbers);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The CustomArrayAdapter class:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, Object[] objects) {

    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
    }
    else{
    v.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
    System.out.println(v.getTag());
    }
    return v;
}
```

Overall what I am trying to set a view to the gridview (In my case every cell contains 1 editText) when this happens I want to assign that editText a tag that will match it's position in numbers[]. I am unsure if you code I have now will do that but because getView is never called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not passed the array of objects to the parent ArrayAdapter class, so it thinks that there are zero items to show.

Change your constructor to this:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, Object[] objects) {

        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
        }
        else{
        v.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
        System.out.println(v.getTag());
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was this issue. The reason the constructor was missing this was because of an error. Apparently the correct fix was to cast objects to a string[]. I however deleted variable because it was the first fix in the list that java gave me. Anyway, thank you again.